Adapting piano score for guitar
I am interested in techniques for adapting piano scores for guitar. The very first issue that one often runs into is the restrictions due to the guitar frequency range, which is limited from below by E2 (in standard tuning, going above E5 is also not very welcome, see also Scientific pitch notation)
Taking as an example Hymne à l'amour: in the following fragment the melody and bass reach their highest and lowest (respectively) points - D5 and B1, that is 2 1/2 tones below the he E2 string.

One solution is simply moving the whole score 2 1/2 tones up, to C-dur. It may pose some challenges with high notes, but on a guitar with 20 frets it is doable. (Alternatively, one could tune the guitar 2 1/2 tones lower.)
Another approach is taking the chord sequence and reharmonizing the melody from scratch.
The third approach - the one that interests me here - is whether/how one could reharmonize only the problematic parts, which  are relatively few in this piece.

In fact, the whole problem here is due to the octave jumps by bass, so naïvely one could simply repeat the bass on the same place, without a jump. However, I wonder, if this would violate any rules of the standard tonal harmony.

Remark: Judging by the guitar adaptations of this piece, a version of the transposition approach (first bullet above) is to reduce the space between the bass and the melody by an octave, while cutting out most of the middle voices of the harmony.

First, ignoring the octave jumps in the bass line would NOT violate any rules for tonal harmony, so in this piece you can simply transpose up any bass notes that is lower than E2.  This makes the melody range to be B3 to D5 and the bass range to be E2 to G3 (transposing down the 2 measure where the E minor chord is in the Treble clef).
From the little I know playing classical guitar, wouldn't the sweet spot is when you play the bass in the lowest 2 strings (E2 and A2), the melody in the upper 2 strings (B3 and E4), and the harmony is using the strings in between? The melody happens to be using only the first 10 frets on the 2 highest strings, while the bass happens to need only the first 5 frets on the 3 lowest strings.
Therefore I recommend staying in G major and simply transpose those bass notes below E2 an octave higher.  Then you don't have to reharmonize but simply build each chord using whatever notes happen to be available on the remaining strings besides the 2 strings already used by the bass and the melody.

Thank you for these valuable suggestions. The reason for my question is that harmony texts recommend, e.g., that in VI-V progression the bass should move by a second and not by a seventh. Moving one of the notes by an octave would violate this rule.

@RogerV. Keep in mind that harmony texts usually prescribe SATB harmony, not pop songs.  Bass line moving in opposite direction of the melody is actually quite good.  But then, I don't see a VI-V progression in the score, only ii-V7 (La min -> Re 7) and IV-V7 (Do -> Re 7) and I-V7-I (Sol -> Re7 -> Sol).  Which measure number are you concerned with?

First of all just because you theoretically have 3 octaves on the guitar doesn't mean you actually can make use of the full three octaves. Like fingering an idk f2 an f5 would mean you have to cover 12 frets and 6 strings between thumb and pinky, good luck with that.
Also as that is apparently a SONG, it's very likely that people are very familiar with the melody of it, so if you want to keep it recognizable it's probably wise to preserve that part.
Or the other way around you could also largely ignore the melody part (leave it to the singer) and instead focus more on the accompaniment. So far the piano seems to also play what the singer sings, but you might not have to.
Also you could just look at what notes being played and what chords they form and try to play those chords and notes irrespective of whether they are the exact notes in the sheet. So ikd the first chord has 2 A's an E and a C. So if you'd strum your A minor chord you also cover those exact notes multiple times.
And then listen if that is already close enough to what you want to accomplish or whether you think there's some tweaking that needs to be done with that.
